# Error on libcurl.dll when using GDAL of OSGeo4W in Django

Tags: django, gdal, geodjango, osgeo

I'm trying to install GeoDjango in my Django project and got weird errors with GDAL.

Following Django documentation, I installed GDAL, GEOS, PROJ using OSGeo4W64, for specific, these are packages I selected to install on OSGeo4W64 setup:

- `gdal v2.3.2-2`
- `geos v3.7.0-1`
- `proj v5.2.0-1`

I also set my environment variables as documented.

---

**What error I got**

At first when I started my Django project (using `runserver`), python tried to look for `gdal202.dll` and raised error **Entry Point Not Found**:

> The procedure entry point sqlite3_column_origin_name could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library **...\osgeo4w64\bin\gdal202.dll**

And one more error **Ordinal Not Found** with **libcurl.dll** (installed by OSGeo4W as dependencies):

> The ordinal 361 could not be located in the dynamic link library
>   **..\osgeo4w64\bin\libcurl.dll**

and python raised error:

> [WinError 182] The operating system cannot run %1

---

**What I did**

I fixed the first error by downgrade `gdal` version to `gdal201.dll` but still can not figure out how to solve the second error.

I tried download the latest Windows binary version of libcurl and replaced with but then I got another error raised by python:

> [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

I also checked for arch of my curl binary is x64 (the same as my python and OSGeo4W).

Hope someone one can help, thanks so much.

Comment: I figured it out. The reason is because `libeay32.dll` (another dependency) were loaded from another directory (because of ordering in PATH). I solved the problem by replacing `libeay32.dll` in OSGeo4W to the overwritten `libeay32.dll`

Comment: You can answer yourself below and approve the answer.

Comment: Where did you find the other version of libeay32.dll (the one other than in the OSGeo4W directory)?

Comment: Never mind, I found it on another machine, oddly enough in the C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin directory.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows w/ Django and PyCharm, I began to receive the same error as one of your earlier ones, as described below:

> The procedure entry point sqlite3_column_origin_name could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal203.dll

### Short-story solution that worked for me

Renamed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\DLLs\sqlite3.dll" to sqlite3.dll.bak

I used two tools to help me resolve this

- [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)
- [Process Explorer 64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

### Steps used to correct

1. Use Dependencies to load up gdal203.dll and look for which DLL is used for sqlite3_column_origin_name
2. Used Process Explorer to determine which sqlite3.dll was being loaded into memory (welcome to DLL-hell). In my case it was in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\DLLs"
3. Used Dependencies to examine the sqlite3.dll from Visual Studio
4. Exited PyCharm and renamed the Visual Studio DLL sqlite3.dll.bak to force it to load up the one according to my PATH order. Who knows what else I may have unintentionally broke by doing this. Future-me might hate me for this.

Starting with a new install of Windows 10, followed by installing PyCharm, Django, GeoDjango... it won't work without substantial troubleshooting in my experience. I think partly from DLL-hell and partly due to PyCharm's runnerw64.exe used to hook in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this was really helpful. In my case I needed to replace the version of sqlite3.dll in my Python install directory (3.9.4) with the version from my OSGeo4W64/bin installation.

Comment: I followed steps 1,2 and 4, and Pycharm's working again. The 'at fault' sqlite3.dll resided C:\Users\andytwoods\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\DLLs